# Authorization header with Angular

Tags: angularjs, authorization

I am trying to send an authorization header with angular. I have debug on my container to display the headers information. When I send the header with postman it works fine, but not with angular.

This is how I tried it with angular:

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic <Base64 String>'
    }
};
$http.get("http://localhost:8888/api/myrest", config)
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.records = response.records;
    });
```

Comment: Please try [this syntax](https://jsfiddle.net/x4yebe80/)

Comment: How does your backend parse the `Authorization` header?

Comment: The auth header is not coming through

Comment: These are the headers send from postman: {host=[localhost:8888], connection=[keep-alive], authorization=[Basic cGlldDpwb21waWVz], cache-control=[no-cache], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36], postman-token=[de2c8374-70f7-384c-17bc-aa450e2d942e], accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, sdch], accept-language=[en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6]}

Comment: These are the headers send from angular: {host=[localhost:8888], connection=[keep-alive], cache-control=[max-age=0], access-control-request-method=[GET], origin=[http://localhost:8000], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36], access-control-request-headers=[accept, authorization], accept=[*/*], referer=[http://localhost:8000/exercise-table.html], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, sdch], accept-language=[en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6]}

Comment: Well `authorization` is in it no?

Comment: Think about the preflight reponse in your backend to allow this.